# http://learnforge.autodesk.io tutorial has error

Tags: autodesk-forge

while trying to run the app created by following all steps on http://learnforge.autodesk.io, I get a 
"(node:18248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer" 
error when trying to create the new bucket.

As I did a clean copy&paste, I think it's not my mistake but the mistake has to be in the provided code.

As I'm new to JS, I can't find the issue myself until now.

And hints?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: If you had read my post, you would know where you find the code ...

Comment: got your question via email, just replied you. thanks

Comment: any solution? i am getting sever error 500 on create bucket.

Comment: Yes, the tutorial will be updated by Autodesk soon to implement more error handling (which was first removed for simplicity). Then the error should not occur without more detail what is wrong.